# loading data from website to hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I need to upload data which is present on a web link say **for example a "blog"** 
to **hdfs** .

Now i was looking through options for accomplishing this could find below link:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop/

but reading through **flume docs** , i am not clear on how i can set up **flume source** 
to point to a website where the blogs content resides .

As per my understanding of the fluem doc there needs to be webserver where i need to deploy a applicationthen weblogs will be generated which will be transferred by flume to hdfs .

But i do not want web server logs , actually i am looking for blogs content (**i.e all data + comments on blogs if any**) which is an unstructured data ,  then i am thinking to process further this data using java map-reduce .

But not sure i am heading in a correct direction .

Also i went through pentaho . But not clear if using PDI i can get the data from a 
website and upload it to hdfs .

Any info on above will be really helpfull.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

Flume can pull the data (as in the case of Twitter) and also data can be pushed to Flume as in the case of server logs using the [FlumeAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-flume-ng/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/flume/appender/FlumeAppender.html).

To get the blogging data into HDFS

a) The blogger application should push the data to HDFS, as in the case of FlumeAppender. Changes have to be done to the blogger application, which is not the case in most of the scenarios.

or

b) Flume can pull the blog data using the appropriate API as in the case of Twitter. [Blogger](https://developers.google.com/blogger/) provides an API to pull the code, which can be used in the Flume source. The Cloudera [blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop/) has [reference](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/tree/master/flume-sources/src/main/java/com/cloudera/flume/source) to Flume code to pull the data from Twitter.

Comment: Thanks praveen . I tried using Bloggers API but unable to use the same since java specifi api is not complete getting compilation errors after adding google api jars . It needs google service api jar which is mentioned in the blooger api docs but could not find the jar online .       Either case have to write custom api or else i am not sure what i can do in this case.